# opencv 3.0 beta create new module (usable in Python)

Tags: python, opencv, module

I have locally added a module to OpenCV 3.0 beta (in a local contrib repository) that is working fine in C++. Now I am trying to make it work in Python, without success.

As suggested [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/CodingStyleGuide) I replaced my `CV_EXPORTS` by `CV_EXPORTS_W` and added the macro `CV_WRAP` to the functions in my classes I want to be able to call in Python (as explained [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_bindings/py_bindings_basics/py_bindings_basics.html)).

Also I found out by looking in source code that I have to add some `WRAP python` in the `CMakeLists.txt` of my module that look like that :

```
set(the_description "Extended video processing module. Includes an object tracker")
set(OPENCV_MODULE_IS_PART_OF_WORLD OFF)
ocv_define_module(xvideo opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui WRAP python)

target_link_libraries(opencv_xvideo)
```

But it looks like I am still missing something since my classes and methods does not exist in Python. For example, the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
frameManager = cv2.FrameManager.create()
```

produces the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FrameManager'
```

As a complementary info, I found out that my classes appear in the generated file (at compilation) `build/modules/python2/pyopencv_generated_include.h` :

```
...
#include "opencv2/xvideo/framemanager.hpp"
...
```

but do not appear in the other `pyopencv_generated_*.h` files.

Do you have any info on what I'm missing here ? or do you know a guide on how to extend OpenCV 3.0 with new modules ? (didn't find any)

Comment: hmm, [according to docs](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/df/da2/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_bindings.html) , it all looks correct so far. still -  if you had a static create() method in your FrameManager, wouldn't that be translated as `frameManager = cv2.FrameManager_create()` ?

Comment: That's the case effectively, I will try your proposition

Comment: Got same error but with `FrameManager_create` instead of `FrameManager`

Comment: also, following opencv's conventions, your c++ code should be in cv::xvideo (nested namespace) and it would appear in python as: `cv2.xvideo.FrameManager`

Comment: Ok actually my module works directly under the cv namespace (did not use another nested namespace) and worked fine in C++, do you think I should transform all of it under a nested xvideo namespace ?

Comment: at least try. hard to say, where the poor wrapper script got confused ;)

Comment: Ok I will try that and tell if it works. Thanks again (just realized you also answer my other questions ^^)

Comment: Ok tried the nested namespace but still the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xvideo'`. It seems that already existing modules have something more I don't, I can't figure out what :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the previous answer (thanks @berak) I transformed that code to little by little get to my very code. As far as I got I can say at least 2 things :

**Do not use a reference to an abstract pure class :**

Transform `myFunction(abstractType &myObject)` to `myFunction(Ptr<abstractType> myObject)` where `Ptr` are OpenCV smart pointers.

**Do not forget to help OpenCV for output function arguments passed by reference :**

For example : `myFunction(CV_OUT SomeType &output)`. PS : There is also the `CV_IN_OUT` keyword. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_bindings/py_bindings_basics/py_bindings_basics.html#bindings-basics) for more details.

**I still have problems with nested namespaces :**

I was using some argument of function of the type `std::string`. It appears that at compilation step, the generated files (`pyopencv_generated_*.h`) for bindings are not correct (they used `string` instead of `std::string`) producing an error when creating the file `cv2.so` : `error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope`. I bypassed that error by using the class `String` instead of `std::string` which seems to be part of OpenCV.

But since I did not really solve the problem, now I have the same error but with some `std::vector<...>` argument. Unfortunately, I can not give a link to the bitbucket of the project (private) but I made a simple sample code facing the same error if someone knows what is wrong. There is the sample code :

**`xxxvideo/include/opencv2/xxxvideo.hpp`** :

```
#ifndef __OPENCV_XXXVIDEO_HPP__
#define __OPENCV_XXXVIDEO_HPP__

/** @defgroup xxxvideo Additional video processing algorithms
*/

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
//#include "xxxvideo/framemanager_all.hpp"

namespace cv {
namespace xxxvideo {

class CV_EXPORTS_W DynamicState : public Algorithm
{
    public:
        virtual ~DynamicState(){};
        CV_WRAP virtual Mat toMatrix();
};

class CV_EXPORTS_W DynamicModel : public Algorithm
{
    public:
        virtual ~DynamicModel(){};
        CV_WRAP virtual std::vector< Ptr<DynamicState> > getAllStates();
};

}}

#endif
```

**`xxxvideo/src/dynamicmodelimpl.cpp`** :

```
#include "opencv2/xxxvideo.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xxxvideo;

vector< Ptr<DynamicState> > DynamicModel::getAllStates()
{
    vector< Ptr<DynamicState> > states;
    return states;
}

Mat DynamicState::toMatrix()
{
    Mat m;
    return m;
}
```

**`xxxvideo/CMakeLists.txt`** :

```
set(the_description "Exxxtended video processing module. Includes an object tracker")
set(OPENCV_MODULE_IS_PART_OF_WORLD OFF)
ocv_define_module(xxxvideo opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui WRAP python)

target_link_libraries(opencv_xxxvideo)
```

And there is the error I get :

```
[ 98%] Generating pyopencv_generated_include.h, pyopencv_generated_funcs.h, pyopencv_generated_types.h, pyopencv_generated_type_reg.h, pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_python2
[ 98%] Building CXX object modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o
In file included from /home/matthieu/libs/opencv/opencv-trunk/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:1217:0:
/home/matthieu/libs/opencv/opencv-trunk/build/modules/python2/pyopencv_generated_types.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_cv_xxxvideo_xxxvideo_DynamicModel_getAllStates(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/matthieu/libs/opencv/opencv-trunk/build/modules/python2/pyopencv_generated_types.h:15927:5: error: ‘vector_Ptr_DynamicState’ was not declared in this scope
     vector_Ptr_DynamicState retval;
     ^
```

If you have any idea on what is wrong, help is welcomed ;)

**##################        EDIT :       ##################**

So I went looking into how Python bindings are generated (starting of an explanation can be found [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6618/how-python-api-is-generated/)). The relevant files are in the folder `modules/python/src2`. I found 2 things that might be related to my problem.

First, all `vector<...>` types used in OpenCV seems to be defined in file `cv2.cpp` between lines 87 and 110 :

```
typedef std::vector<uchar> vector_uchar;
typedef std::vector<char> vector_char;
typedef std::vector<int> vector_int;
typedef std::vector<float> vector_float;
typedef std::vector<double> vector_double;
typedef std::vector<Point> vector_Point;
typedef std::vector<Point2f> vector_Point2f;
typedef std::vector<Vec2f> vector_Vec2f;
typedef std::vector<Vec3f> vector_Vec3f;
typedef std::vector<Vec4f> vector_Vec4f;
typedef std::vector<Vec6f> vector_Vec6f;
typedef std::vector<Vec4i> vector_Vec4i;
typedef std::vector<Rect> vector_Rect;
typedef std::vector<KeyPoint> vector_KeyPoint;
typedef std::vector<Mat> vector_Mat;
typedef std::vector<DMatch> vector_DMatch;
typedef std::vector<String> vector_String;
typedef std::vector<Scalar> vector_Scalar;

typedef std::vector<std::vector<char> > vector_vector_char;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<Point> > vector_vector_Point;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<Point2f> > vector_vector_Point2f;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<Point3f> > vector_vector_Point3f;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<DMatch> > vector_vector_DMatch;
```

Second, the `std::` namespace is removed from the argument types in file `hdr_parser.py` in function `def parse_arg(self, arg_str, argno):` on line 204 :

```
arg_type = self.batch_replace(arg_type, [("std::", ""), ("cv::", ""), ("::", "_")])
```

**My partial solution :**

Looking into this and in my error I came up with the idea of adding one typedef in the file `xxxvideo.hpp` just after definition of class `DynamicState` :

```
typedef std::vector< cv::Ptr<DynamicState> >  vector_Ptr_DynamicState;
```

Compilation errors are gone, but now, I have an error when I `import cv2` in python :

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/opencv/opencv-trunk/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN2cv8xxxvideo12DynamicStateE
```

Again, if someone has any idea on what I should do, or if you could relay my question to someone who might, I would be grateful.

**##################        EDIT (Again):       ##################**

Actually my error vanished after another round of `cmake ..`, `make`, ,`sudo make install`. This seems to have corrected the error.

Comment: do not use `namespace cv::xxxvideo` , but put the code **inside** namespace cv { namespace xxxvideo { ... }}   (in the very same way you did in the header. else your linker thinks, it is in global [it is not])

Comment: @berak Thank you for that explanation but the error remains (the same). would you know where to focus my search if you don't know why ?

Comment: @berak As a starting point, I found [that](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6618/how-python-api-is-generated/) link on how OpenCV generates the bindings so I went looking into those files (in folder `modules/python/src2`). I remarked 2 things that could be in relation with my problem (but I might be wrong). In file `cv2.cpp`, between lines 87 and 110, there are typedefs of `std::vector<...>` types. And in file `hdr_parser.py`, in function `parse_arg(...)` there is that line : `arg_type = self.batch_replace(arg_type, [("std::", ""), ("cv::", ""), ("::", "_")])`. Will keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

ok, seems i have to try my own dogfood here..

#### xvideo/include/opencv2/xvideo.hpp:

```
#ifndef __OPENCV_xvideo_HPP__
#define __OPENCV_xvideo_HPP__

/** @defgroup xvideo Additional video processing algorithms
*/

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

namespace cv {
namespace xvideo {

    struct CV_EXPORTS_W FrameManager
    {
        CV_WRAP void foo(InputArray inp, float v);

        CV_WRAP static Ptr<FrameManager> create();
    };
}
}
```

#### xvideo/src/framemanager.cpp:

```
#include "opencv2/xvideo.hpp"

namespace cv
{
namespace xvideo
{


    void FrameManager::foo(InputArray inp, float v) {}

    Ptr<FrameManager> FrameManager::create() { return makePtr<FrameManager>(); }

}
}
```

same CmakeLists.txt, you were using.

now run cmake(-gui) , see, that BUILD_opencv_xvideo=ON, configure,generate.

then rebuild, and **don't forget to run `make install`** (or build the INSTALL proj. in VS)

```
>>> help(cv2.xvideo)
Help on module cv2.xvideo in cv2:

NAME
    cv2.xvideo

FILE
    (built-in)

FUNCTIONS
    FrameManager_create(...)
        FrameManager_create() -> retval


>>> fm = cv2.xvideo.FrameManager_create()
>>> help(fm)
Help on xvideo_FrameManager object:

class xvideo_FrameManager(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __repr__(...)
 |      x.__repr__() <==> repr(x)
 |
 |  foo(...)
 |      foo(inp, v) -> None
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |
 |  __new__ = <built-in method __new__ of type object>
 |      T.__new__(S, ...) -> a new object with type S, a subtype of T
```

Comment: ok thank you so much, that means it can work but it also means I did something wrong although I don't find what (did not forgot to install). I will try to work on that to explain why mine does not work and will keep you updated.

Comment: By the way, was your module done in the official OpenCV repository or the contrib one ?

Comment: is there a way in SO I can make some kind of comment but with multiple line code? Or should I do an answer (which should not be appropriate I think) ?

Comment: ^^ not really. dare to make an answer.

Comment: So I have been trying to transform the code little by little from your working example to my code and at one step there is a problem. (not sure this is the only one but a beginning). When I am using a `string` function argument (`std::string` in header and `using namespace std` in `.cpp`), it produces an error at the step when it tries to create the file `pyopencv_generated_types.h`. The error is `error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope`. Could you try if you have the same error ?

Comment: It appears that I solved this problem by using the class `String` instead of `std::string` but I am not sure where this class is defined (If it is raw C++, id did not know I'm quite new to C++). I found one declaration in file `platforms/android/service/engine/jni/Tests/gtest/gtest.h` but it does not seem to be that. Anyway it solved my problem, let's go to the next one ^^.

Comment: if you need to use std::string, you have to put `#include <string>` into your xvideo.hpp header. (the generated .h files do not see any declarations in your .cpp file, they only see the hrader)

Comment: Actually I did. Anyway, I'm continuing my transformation crusade. Will keep you updated when I am finished.

Comment: I can not avoid my curse anymore ^^, there is no class `Vector` and I have the same error with `std::vector` that I had with `std::string`. The error raised is `pyopencv_generated_types.h:15266:5: error: ‘vector_Ptr_DynamicState’ was not declared in this scope` and it corresponds to the following line of code : `CV_WRAP virtual std::vector< Ptr<DynamicState> > getAllStates() = 0;` As you can see (`=0`), this is in a pure abstract class. I wonder if it is the reason why the "replacement" type `vector_Ptr_DynamicState` is not created. I will investigate that.

Comment: any chance, you can put it on github or such ?

Comment: I wish I could ^^. It's a private project in the context of my internship. But once I find out what is wrong I will try to make an answer as thorough as possible.